# Convolution of Complex vectors

Tags: julia

I was doing some mathematical computing using Julia (which I'm not that familiar with) and needed to use convolution of vectors with comples entries. However, it seems that the usual `conv` function from the DSP package does not support it.

A Google search did not bring up any question or issue about that, nor any alternative. Is there any other package which offers complex convolution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using the DSP module's conv function? It works with complex:

```
julia> using DSP

julia> a = [1, 2, 1, 2]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 1
 2

julia>         b = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> acom = complex.(a) .+ 2.9* im

julia> bcom = complex.(b) .+ 4.5 * im

julia> conv(acom,bcom)
6-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
 -12.049999999999999 + 7.399999999999997im
               -22.1 + 22.200000000000003im
              -31.15 + 35.400000000000006im
 -29.150000000000006 + 39.900000000000006im
               -19.1 + 28.0im
  -7.049999999999999 + 17.699999999999996im
```

Comment: A more elegant way to 'complexify' `a` is `complex.(a, 2.9)`. Also, `a .+ 2.9im` works. They are all equally fast.